# Service that execute sndPlaySound does not generate sound on MS RDP

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, windows-services, playsound

We have created a windows service that use **sndPlaySound** function to play wav file and it works locally when we are operating that machine physically. If I connect to that machine via Remote Desktop Connection it does not play sound. Is there any limitation or I require any other driver or something ? One thing to note that this works via VM Ware Remote Console. Your help is appreciated.

Comment: Does your service run on the remote machine or on your local one? Is the rdp connection properly configured to forward audio streams?

Answer (score 0):

This one isn't really a Stack Overflow kind of question, since it's nothing to do with your program itself, but anyway...

When sound doesn't work correctly in an RDP session it's usually because the connection itself isn't configured to direct the sound correctly. The default RDP profile disables both playback and recording on the connection, making it basically the same as if the server/computer has no sound card. You can adjust this in the RDP settings:

- Run `mstsc` without parameters.
- Set server name.
- Click **Show Options** to access the full configuration.
- On **Local Resources**, under *Remote audio*, click the **Settings...** button.
- Configure playback and recording options.
- Save (or *Save As...*) to create an RDP profile file so you don't have to do this every time.

There are no command line parameters that do the same, but you can reference the `.rdp` configuration file if running from the command line.

Comment: I enable all resources when connecting to the machine and audio feature is also enabled.  I am performing this test to reproduce a specific problem in one software. when my software is running as an application it plays sound but when it runs as a service it is not able to play.

Comment: @Dhruv Doesn't play at all or doesn't play on your local machine over the RDP connection?

Comment: 1.)if running as an application 
connected physically on machine - works,
connected via remote desktop - works,

2.) if running as a service
connected physically on machine - works,
connected via remote desktop - does not work,

Comment: @Dhruv Sorry for the delay... have you checked that the sound isn't playing on the host machine when you're connected via RDP?

Comment: Host machine is Virtual machine only, but I guess should play through RDP driver

Comment: The service doesn't have access to the RDP connection's sound device then. I'd be willing to bet that it's trying to play on the host's sound device, if it has one. You'll need a program running in the user's RDP session to play sound through.

Comment: I have raised ticket with Microsoft as there is issue for this function when using MS RDP. Same service plays sound if connected through VM Ware console.